# Slowly Rendered Html page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, notepad++

I am trying to make a Sign-UP form in html and CSS with notepad++ but whenever I try to run it on chrome, it loads very slowly. Is it a configuration error or something? What am I doing wrong? Is there a plugin needed? This is my entire code:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Register</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="full_name" class="col-md-4 ">Full Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="full-name">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email_address" class="col-md-4 ">E-Mail Address</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="email-address">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="user_name" class="col-md-4 ">User Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="username">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 ">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password"  class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6 stylish" offset-md-4>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"">
                            Register
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have too many quotes in your Register button’s class (note the inconsistent text color). If that’s how it really is, then the invalid html may be causing your browser to hang while it figures out how to deal with it.

Comment: I would recommend you run your html through a validator (the entire page and not just the body), and see if it finds any invalid syntax. https://validator.w3.org

Comment: Also, you say you posted it entirely. If that’s true, you’re missing your opening html tag, and your head tag.

Comment: There's also the opening `<form>` tag missing (see, I've fixed indentation for you and that became somewhat obvious)

Comment: Can we take a look to the web page? Is it available online somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

- Add the bootstrap and jQuery plugins.
- In HTML page link the external files properly.
- In head section add the external links.
- Maintain the folder structure neat so that linking extrnal files is easy.
- If everything is correct go to this link to set up Chrome: https://www.webnots.com/fix-slow-page-loading-issue-in-google-chrome/

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">Register</div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="full_name" class="col-md-4 ">Full Name</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="full-name">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="email_address" class="col-md-4 ">E-Mail Address</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="email-address">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="user_name" class="col-md-4 ">User Name</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="username">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 ">Password</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input type="password"  class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                        <div class="col-md-6 stylish" offset-md-4>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"">
                                            Register
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```